# No such key :Enter after migration from Poltergeist to Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to get specs passing in an old Rails 4 project after migration from Poltergeist to Selenium WebDriver/ChromeDriver. Typical failure around `.native.send_key(:Enter)`

Is there an equivalent or best practice we should switch to?

```
  17) Comment creation for image changes counter
  Failure/Error: find('input[name="comment[body]"]').native.send_key(:Enter)

  Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnsupportedOperationError:
    no such key :Enter
  # ./spec/support/helpers/comments_page_helpers.rb:13:in `add_comment'
  # ./spec/features/comments/creation_spec.rb:72:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # ./spec/features/comments/creation_spec.rb:71:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

*#spec/features/comments/creation_spec.rb*

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Comment creation', type: :feature, js: true do
  ...
  context 'for image' do
    background do
      open_image_comments_modal section_position: 1, photo_position: 1

      within '.modal-comments-container' do
        add_comment 'First comment message'
      end
    end
  ...
end
```

*#spec/support/helpers/comments_page_helpers.rb*

```
module CommentsPageHelpers
  ...
  def add_comment(text)
    fill_in 'comment[body]', with: text
    find('input[name="comment[body]"]').native.send_key(:Enter)

    expect(page).to have_css '.comments .comment-body', text: text
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to send the enter key you shouldn't be calling anything on `native` and you should be using lowercase for the symbols, which would then work with Poltergeist or Selenium as the driver

```
find('input[name="comment[body]"]').send_keys(:enter)
```

See https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#send_keys-instance_method